# TYPO3 9.5.8, fe_login in mixed language

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

in a recently upgraded installation of typo3 to 9.5.8 i am confronted with the problem, that fe_login shows mixed languages. Some labels are in german, but the error texts only in english.

I tried to update the languages in install tool (manage language packs) but nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Thanks 
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Typo3 cannot find a valid translation in the translation-file it will always output the value of the base language (english).
The only reference I have is sadly typo3 8, but as long as nothing changed for version 9 it shoud be located here:

```
/typo3conf/l10n/de/felogin/Resources/Private/Language/de.locallang.xlf
```

Maybe check if the file exists and if it has translations for every key.

Comment: it seems that the german language file is not complete. Most entries are missing. So there is no solution ... But i will declare it the right anwer because it describes the reason.